# Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro relating to Volte

Tags: voice-over-lte

Straight Talk, my carrier, informed me that my phone Xiaomi Mi 9T pro is not capable of using Volte. My phone states it is enabled for Volte. Also has an icon (volte) next to my status bar. I was also told I could lose my service end of Feb. 2022 if I did not get one of their phones. At this stage I don't know what to believe. Any answers?

Comment: Didi they really told you that your phone is "not capable"? I would assume they simply have a list of devices they have tested to support VoLTE and all the others are simply unknown if they support VoLTE or not. You can try to disable 2G and 3G on your phone (not sure if this is possible in that combination) so that only 4G and 5G remains. If calling still works then VoLTE is active and working.

Comment: They did tell me my service would not be the same end of Feb. 2022, dropped calls, poor reception. They offered a free phone which was a bunch of crap and one refurbished. My phone is enabled for Volte. Its unlocked (GSM) 2G/3G/4G It has an AT&T sim card. I don't know what to do. I am not that savvy with phones.

Comment: you tell us in march

Comment: I'm afraid we can't tell anything better than their customer service. Looks like they have [a list of VoLTE compatible devices](https://extras.straighttalk.com/en/survival-guide) (I can't open the link from here though). For example, AT&T has to [do a device certification for it to support VoLTE](https://forums.att.com/conversations/other-phones-devices/att-volte-phone-list-what-do-some-have-that-others-dont-good-looks-and-money/61d0e68dcc27ce2d782e8c5f?commentId=61d0e757cc27ce2d782e8c88).

Comment: Checked with a number of other cell carriers because of Straight Talk decision. Most did except my phone. Which is Volte enabled on my phone as well as a Volte icon next to my status bar. I guess S/T is looking to sell their phones.

Comment: 3G Networks Phase Out. AT&T Feb. 2022. T-Mobile Sprint 3G CDMA 3/31/22. Sprint 4G LTE 6/30/22. T-Mobile 3G UMT- 7/1/22. I assume you all know T-Mobile and Sprint are the same company.